# Disable text hover effect

Tags: jquery, css

So I am trying to disable the "hover" state of a text tspan tag. I have an element below that already has an hover state and whenever I place the mouse over the text the hover effect "flashes". I want the text to be ignored in the hover state.

See in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/neveldo/jh4jzyhw/), the "Morbihan" area, when we place the mouse over the text "Morbihan", the hover effect of the area flashes. The same happens to the tooltip, I want to disable that effect, when hovering the text just continue with the tooltip and highlight color of the area.

http://jsfiddle.net/neveldo/jh4jzyhw/

So far I only disabled the text cursor:

```
    tspan {
        cursor: default;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not super clear what functionality you desire. Maybe clarify: what _should_ happen when you mouseover "Morbihan"? Also - the map is in an iframe so the local css won't apply. Take a closer look at the mapael docs maybe http://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/

Comment: When I mouseover the text I dont want it to trigger any action, just like the text wasnt there, when I mouseover the text now it disables the hover effect of the green highlight of the area. I want the text to be "invisible" to the mouse.

Comment: Maybe try `tspan:hover {display:none;}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`pointer-events:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the `text` element.

```
text {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Note that applying that styling to the `tspan` will not work. If you need to do that, you'll need to use jQuery to apply the style to the parent `text` element. Something like `$('tspan').parent().css({ pointerEvents: 'none' });`  (pseudo-code, untested)

http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/jh4jzyhw/155/

Comment: That's it, that you so much!